git@gitlab.instance.ch: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
I followed exactly the guide here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html#add-an-ssh-key-to-your-gitlab-account to the letter. For some reason I still cannot ssh to the instance...
Here is the full output to ssh -Tvvv git@gitlab.instance.ch:
(base) username@cwe-513-vml315 ~ $ ssh -Tvvv git@gitlab.instance.ch
OpenSSH_8.7p1, OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /afs/instance.ch/user/l/username/.ssh/config
debug1: /afs/instance.ch/user/l/username/.ssh/config line 27: Applying options for gitlab.instance.ch
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 55: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host gitlab.instance.ch originally gitlab.instance.ch
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 3: not matched 'final'
debug2: match not found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1 (parse only)
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512]
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 55: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/acc_ssh.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/acc_ssh.conf
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/acc_ssh.conf line 17: Applying options for *.instance.ch
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/acc_ssh.conf line 28: Applying options for *.*
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/acc_ssh.conf line 36: Applying options for *
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /afs/instance.ch/user/l/username/.ssh/config
debug1: /afs/instance.ch/user/l/username/.ssh/config line 27: Applying options for gitlab.instance.ch
debug2: add_identity_file: ignoring duplicate key /afs/instance.ch/user/l/username/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 55: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host gitlab.instance.ch originally gitlab.instance.ch
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 3: matched 'final'
debug2: match found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512]
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 55: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/acc_ssh.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/acc_ssh.conf
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/acc_ssh.conf line 17: Applying options for *.instance.ch
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/acc_ssh.conf line 28: Applying options for *.*
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/acc_ssh.conf line 36: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "gitlab.instance.ch" port 22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.instance.ch [2001:1458:d00:63::100:377] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 4 IPV6_TCLASS 0x48
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: timeout: 3000 ms remain after connect
debug1: identity file /afs/instance.ch/user/l/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /afs/instance.ch/user/l/username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.7
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.instance.ch:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: no algorithms matched; accept original
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:CVLzbB75iuCp12QrJmPzncBaj1g6GO0ivmSOM++nhoU
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
Warning: Permanently added 'gitlab.instance.ch' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /afs/instance.ch/user/l/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:CUZHyekVK+eFgVixjsexc7op+1tstBpSK802GIUDFo0 explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: preferred publickey
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: 
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /afs/instance.ch/user/l/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:CUZHyekVK+eFgVixjsexc7op+1tstBpSK802GIUDFo0 explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@gitlab.instance.ch: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

The current state of affairs is this: I have multiple keys in my .ssh dir, and multiple of them are now added to ssh keys in git lab. Yet none of them seem to work. I also have the following config file:
Host gitlab.instance.ch
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile /afs/instance.ch/user/l/username/.ssh/id_ed25519

I feel like this really should be quite simple, so I am not sure what is going wrong. Any help/advice would be appreciated cheers
tried adding multiple keys, changing config, restarting PCs yet nothing

You provide IdentityFile and ssh uses it: "debug1: Will attempt key: /afs/instance.ch/user/l/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:CUZHyekVK+eFgVixjsexc7op+1tstBpSK802GIUDFo0 explicit" But have you uploaded the public key to your account at gitlab.instance.ch?

Uploaded afs/instance.ch/user/l/username/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub ?

yes I have, I'm not sure what the "identity" file is doing, but it's there also

Please make sure you've uploaded *.pub files, not private keys; and that you didn't mangle them while uploading; full exact content of *.pub, unchanged.

I did that, with both the comment at the front and back of the pub key being pasted into the box

I would first test with a new key, without passphrase, and with a simpler cryptographic algorithm
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -f ~/.ssh/newKey

Upload ~/.ssh/newKey.pub to your GitLab instance account, and check if a ssh -i ~/.ssh/newKey -T git@gitlab.instance.ch works better.

Gives the exact same error, I am guessing it's something to do with the instance now, because this is three steps and there's not really many places for it to go wrong on my end.

@ellgee On the instance side, are the chmod correct? (as I mentioned here or here)
